# Can the output of the "but: was" clause be customised?

Tags: hamcrest

I am trying to write a custom matcher that navigates deep down the object graph to check an important property.

```java
assertThat( writeRequest, hasRole("admin") );
```

When this fails I'd like to see a message like:

```
Expected: "admin"
     but: was "read-only"
```

However, when the assertion fails, it prints out the `toString()` on the `writeRequest` which means that the information I want would be deep in the string. To make matters worse, along the object graph is a generated class which does not `@Override` `Object.toString()` so that you cannot even find out (without logging or breakpoints) what the actual role the user had was!

So, in Hamcrest, is there any way to customize the output that appears in the `but: was` clause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr:** override [`org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher.describeMismatch(Object item, Description description)`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/40465aa8daaa73912bf2566d260188cb9e863ab3/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/BaseMatcher.java)

---

While running a test using `org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableWithSize` I spotted a test failure with the message:

```
Expected: an iterable with size <1>
     but: iterable size was <0>
```

which has a customised `but` clause!

Looking into [source code for `IterableWithSize`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/master/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableWithSize.java) I notice that the string `"iterable size"` is being passed into [`org.hamcrest.FeatureTypeMatcher`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/40465aa8daaa73912bf2566d260188cb9e863ab3/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/FeatureMatcher.java) as the parameter `featureName`. Traced this up through [`org.hamcrest.TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/40465aa8daaa73912bf2566d260188cb9e863ab3/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher.java) where I spotted the `describeMismatch(Object,Description)` method. Since `BaseMatcher` has an implementation of that method, if you get the IDE to generate stubs of missing methods you'll miss it.